# pytest stdout flush to a different file from the test output

Tags: python, stdout, pytest

Here I have **tests.py** containing:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('log2.log', 'w')


class TestH5Client:
    def test_something(self):
        print("Start")
        assert True
        print("End")

    def teardown_class(cls):
        print("OK")
```

I am running my test with the following shell command

`pytest tests.py::TestH5Client::test_something >>log.log`

and I want that **log.log** to contain the information of the test run and **log2.log** to contain all the prints, but **log2.log** is empty

Content of **log.log** (the content is what I expect):

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.0, pytest-3.1.0, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: C:\Stefans\01.Learning_Python\27.pytest_std_ouput, inifile:
collected 2 items

tests.py .

========================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

Content of **log2.log**: the file is empty

Expectation for **log2.log** content:

```
Start
End
OK
```

So my questions are what I am doing wrong and how can I make it work this way, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the default option of py.test is to capture al output by overriding sys.stdout, cancelling out your code to override sys.stdout.

I have tested three options that seem to solve your problem:

1. Instead of overriding sys.stdout, you could override the print function, like eg `print = lambda x: open('log2.log', 'a').write(str(x)+"\n")`

   - will not log prints recursively
   - enables per file logging
2. You could disable py.test's output capturing by adding the `-s` option to your execution command.

   - will print all prints in all your tests, also recursively
   - non-converted prints will probably cloud your `log.log`-file
3. Use a decent logger framework.

Despite 3 being the biggest effort, depending on what you want to reach, I do believe that this is the best solution.